# Google Drive's Shared Folder: Remove 'Edit User' without files

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

I'm using Google Drive in my no-profit student association. We're 94 members, we have a general Google account for Drive management and all the personal Google accounts of the members have selective editing access to the main folder and (some of) its subfolders.

Now, while time passes, since some students are going to graduate, they must be removed from the folder, but their files should not!

Can this be achieved in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Add an editor" listed as an icon or link at the top of the page of your Google Drive. Click on "Advanced Options" on the following page. Once there, you can change authority to Edit, View Only, or Remove.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have it yet, create an account to be used as "record keeper" or "archivist"
2. Ask the graduating students to change the owner of their files that are work made for your organization to make the "record keeper" the owner of those files.
3. If some student don't do that, make a copy of those files.
4. Remove the students from the folders and from the files that now are owned by the "record keeper" account.

Related Q&A

- [Google Drive documents with transferred ownership don't appear in "My Drive"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79337/88163)